# How to leave path of waypoint system in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a waypoint system for path finding. My object is following the path but when it reaches the last point, the object comeback to first point of waypoint it does not leave the path after reaching last point. Any idea?
I want to develop a 3D game like temple run in which player take a curve using navmesh and waypoint system.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class NavMover : MonoBehaviour {


    List<Transform> points = new List <Transform> ();

    private int destPoint = 0;
    private UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent agent;

    public WaypointSystem path;
    //Assembly-CSharp-firstpass
    public float remainingDistance = 0.3f;

    void Start () {

        points = path.waypoints;

        agent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();

        // Disabling auto-braking allows for continuous movement
        // between points (ie, the agent doesn't slow down as it
        // approaches a destination point).

           // agent.autoBraking = false;


        //GotoNextPoint();
    }


    void GotoNextPoint() {
        // Returns if no points have been set up
        if (points.Count == 0)
            return;
        if (destPoint == points.Count) return;

        // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
        agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;


        // Choose the next point in the array as the destination,
        // cycling to the start if necessary.
        //destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Count;
        destPoint = (destPoint + 1);


    }


    void Update()
    {
        // Choose the next destination point when the agent gets
        // close to the current one.
        if (agent.remainingDistance < remainingDistance)
        {
            GotoNextPoint();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: check the code please ..

Answer (score 0):

Just put 1 more point to off screen so they will go off screen and when they reach it you can destroy or disable them.

Comment: which item i have to destroy ??

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve with this and without seeing any code i am just saying that you should probably destroy your object that follows your waypoints.